# How to use session attribute value with the where clause in Business component view object query.?

Tags: oracle-adf

In the sessionScoped managed bean(registered managed bean in the bounded task flow and also in the adfc-config.xml file) in ADF fusion web application I had set the attribute in the session as

```
FacesContext fctx = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
ExternalContext ectx = fctx.getExternalContext();
HttpSession userSession = (HttpSession) ectx.getSession(false);
userSession.setAttribute("compID", defaultCompany);
```

the session attribute is working fine in the bean and the value is being displayed in the jsff page of the bounded task flow and also on the jsf page which contains the bounded task flow as region

im getting the session attribute value on the page using the expression

```
"#{sessionScope.compID}"
```

inside the output text value property, but not able to get the value in the model project which contains the business components. I want to use the compID session attribute value in the query

```
Select.........where COMP_ID ='compID';
```

by setting the value in the bind variable value property and passing the newly creted bid variable in the where clause but its not working

so i how to use this dynamic session attribute value in the where clause of the query of the business component view object?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try doing what's mentioned in the below blog

http://andrejusb.blogspot.com/2012/01/how-to-access-session-scope-in-adf-bc.html

Answer (score 3):

You need a service method on your VO or AM that accepts a parameter - you call this method in your JSF page and pass the session scope as the parameter.
An example:
https://blogs.oracle.com/shay/entry/passing_parameters_to_an_adf_p
or
https://blogs.oracle.com/shay/entry/am_service_method_-_simple_dem

Comment: ..i want to use the session attribute value in the business component where clause and the value is being set in the session in viewcontroller layer in a session scoped managed bean

Comment: thnks Lines for setting the value in the this.getSession.getUserData.put("key", value) used and worked...Not able to like more than one answer as used some lines from both the answers

Answer (score 1):

my...final solution using code lines from both the answer....

```
protected void prepareSession(Session session) {
Map sessionScope = ADFContext.getCurrent().getSessionScope();
String company = (String)sessionScope.get("compId");
System.out.println("Default Comapny in BC is: " + company);
super.prepareSession(session);
this.getSession().getUserData().put("Company", company);
System.out.println("After setting value in userData map of BC");
}
```

expression used on view xml

```
adf.userSession.userData.Company

![used expression in the bind variable value][1]
```

Comment: you should start using ADFlogger instead of SOP